# Update content of a Dialog with custom view after Click

Tags: android, dialog, android-custom-view, updates, android-dialog

I am using a Dialog to show a sequence of quizzes in Android. I would like to show the next quiz once the user answers True or False.

I am using a custom layout and I am controlling it with the following code:

```
public void showQuizDialog() {
    View v;
    TextView question;
    // Textview showing Quiz 1 out of 3
    TextView numQ;
    NetworkImageView image;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    // The coordinator keeps track of the game
    coordinator.setQuizStarted();
    // Get the quiz using the coordinator
    Quiz qX = coordinator.getQuiz();
    final String answer = qX.getAnswer();
    final String quizTracker = coordinator.getTracker();

    // Create an instance of the dialog fragment
    AlertDialog.Builder quiz = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = MyActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_layout,null);

    // Set the question
    question = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.content_quiz);
    question.setText(qX.getQuestion());

    // Set current number of question
    numQ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.number_quiz);
    numQ.setText(quizTracker);

    // Retrieves the image from url
    image = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_quiz);
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    String urlImage = getCompleteUrl(CODE_QUIZ_IMG);
    urlImage += qX.getImg();
    image.setImageUrl(urlImage, imageLoader);


    quiz.setPositiveButton("True", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                if (answer.equals(quiz_true)) {
                    coordinator.notifyCorrectQuizNum();
                    Log.d(QUIZ_DIALOG,"\t\tCorrect answer! it was true");
                }
                coordinator.setQuizEnded(true);
                coordinator.updateQuizLeft();
            }
        })
      .setNegativeButton("False", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked to False btn

                        if (answer.equals(quiz_false)){
                            Log.d(QUIZ_DIALOG,"\t\tCorrect Answer!! It was false");
                            coordinator.notifyCorrectQuizNum();
                        }
                        coordinator.setQuizEnded(true);
                        coordinator.updateQuizLeft();
                    }
                });

    quiz.setView(v);

    final AlertDialog dialog = quiz.create();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Let's say there are 100 quizzes to show and a method of the Coordinator class that returns the number of remaining quizzes.

So, after the call

```
coordinator.setQuizEnded(true);
coordinator.updateQuizLeft();
```

the `coordinator.getQuizLeft()` will return 99. And `coordinator.getQuiz()` will point to the next quiz.

How do I update the `TextView question` and `numQ` without closing the dialog?

Comment: Thanks @Andriy Omelchenko for the tag edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this :

setupQuizDialog() which is called first and creates a dialog without any content.

loadNewQuestionIntoDialog() which is continuously called to refresh the content of the dialog with a new question.

```
    public void setupQuizDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = MyActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_layout,null);

    AlertDialog.Builder quiz = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
            .setPositiveButton("True", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Nothing, will replace later
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("False", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Nothing, will replace later
                }
            });
    quiz.setView(v);

    final AlertDialog dialog = quiz.create();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    loadNewQuestionIntoDialog(dialog, 100);
}

public void loadNewQuestionIntoDialog(final AlertDialog dialog, final int questionNumber){

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    // The coordinator keeps track of the game
    coordinator.setQuizStarted();
    // Get the quiz using the coordinator
    final String answer = qX.getAnswer();
    final String quizTracker = coordinator.getTracker();

    TextView question = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.content_quiz);
    question.setText(qX.getQuestion());

    TextView numQ = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.number_quiz);
    numQ.setText(quizTracker);

    // Retrieves the image from url
    NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_quiz);
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    String urlImage = getCompleteUrl(CODE_QUIZ_IMG);
    urlImage += qX.getImg();
    image.setImageUrl(urlImage, imageLoader);

    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // User clicked OK button
            if (answer.equals(quiz_true)) {
                coordinator.notifyCorrectQuizNum();
                Log.d(QUIZ_DIALOG,"\t\tCorrect answer! it was true");
            }
            coordinator.setQuizEnded(true);
            if(questionNumber > 0)
                loadNewQuestionIntoDialog(dialog, coordinator.updateQuizLeft());
        }
    });
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // User clicked to False btn

            if (answer.equals(quiz_false)){
                Log.d(QUIZ_DIALOG,"\t\tCorrect Answer!! It was false");
                coordinator.notifyCorrectQuizNum();
            }
            coordinator.setQuizEnded(true);
            if(questionNumber > 0)
                loadNewQuestionIntoDialog(dialog, coordinator.updateQuizLeft());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The dialog's components are updated correctly